# Bootstrap Submenu not open on hover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap navbar in parent menu it should be onclick

but sub menu should be onhover left side but it's not working

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-uppercase">
                        <li><a id="Home" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <!-- Visa drapdown-->
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> My Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 01</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 01</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 02</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 03</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 04</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> My Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
                                        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 01</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 01</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 02</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 03</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 04</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

How to fix this issue

in topmenu onclick fine but submenu should be onhover

and open left side

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your submneu on onhover left side then add ".dropdown-menu-right" intead of ".dropdown-menu-left" and add the bottom style to your stylesheet

.dropdown-menu-right { right: 100%; left: auto; }
.dropdown-menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu { display:block;}

Answer (score -1):

just add this css to to your stylesheet, I hope it will work

```
.dropdown-menu .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu { display:block;}
```